# c++ dynamic allocation with new

Tags: c++, dynamic

What's the difference between these two allocations?

```
CPolygon trgl;
CPolygon * ppoly2 = &trgl;
```

and

```
CPolygon * ppoly2 = new CPolygon();
```

Comment: You should delete the 2nd one, but mustn't delete the first one.

Comment: One is default-initialized and one is value-initialized.

Comment: @Adriano True. Even better, you could accompany such comments with a link to the [list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) here on SO.

Comment: @Angew I added that post to my favorites, next time I'll use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` creates a dynamic object on the heap, while the first syntax create the object either in the global memory section, or on the stack.

As a consequence, if the object is allocated on the stack, it will be automatically deleted if the object goes out of scope. If the object is global, it will stay for the liftime of the process.

Object allocated with `new` would have to be deleted with `delete`.